# grep variable rather than file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I want to be able to check if a variable containing a string matches a regular expression pattern. I know how to do this with a file using `grep` but I want to be able to do it using just a string.

For example to find if a variable contains a file name for a .gif I want to be able to do something along the lines of this.

```bsh
$ STRING=image.gif
$ grep "\.gif$" $STRING
```

When I run this I get this error.

```
grep: image.gif: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I can get `grep` treat "image.gif" as the string I want to search rather than the name of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
echo "$STRING" | grep "\.gif$"
```

Since `grep` is capable of reading from `stdin` you can adapt this to any number of situations (including file IO with `cat`, though that's generally a bad idea because streaming is more efficient).

Comment: You are likely to want `echo "$STRING"` with double quotes around the variable.  That preserves newlines and other white space, whereas if you omit the double quotes, everything is on one line.  In this context, it may not matter, but it is a good idea to (double) quote first and think later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very good point, particularly if you intend to use the result of grep for something other than just checking if it matched a regex (e.g., going on to pipe it into `awk` or `sed`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a bash "here string" to grep from a variable:

```
grep '\.gif$' <<< "$STRING"
```

Comment: Nice; has the advantage of not creating a subshell (unlike the `echo ... | ...` approach). However, generally, you should use `"$STRING"` (double-quoting) in order to avoid potentially unwanted shell expansions (interpretation of the variable value by the shell).

Comment: Yes, I should have used `"$STRING"`, though for PO's example, `$STRING` and `"$STRING"` make no difference, thanks for pointing out that